# putting record from mysql into array in php with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm strugging to get to grips with this mysqli style of queries. Can someone help me with this code please?

The intention is to put the results from the query (or which there are three in the database) into an array so that I can display them in a table, for example.

Here is my code...

```
$get_orders_stmt = $db->prepare(
            "select cap_transaction_id, company_id, company_transaction_id, cap_points, transaction2login
                from transactions
                where transaction2login = ?");
            $get_orders_stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['username']); 
            $get_orders_stmt->execute();
            while($row = $get_orders_stmt->fetch()) {
                $results[] = $row;
                print_r($results);
```

I was hoping to put $row as the returned records into the array, results but I fear I have got this totally wrong! My print_r() gives me this...

```
Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 )
```

Any thoughts or pointer please?

UPDATE!
Turns out the my machine isn't up to spec with the best answer on here. I need MYSQLIND for get_results(); I'm moving to something more compatible.

Comment: Maybe the result is confusing you because your print_r is in your loop and you output it multiple times?

Comment: Duplicate of the whole "Related" column at the right side -->

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). mysqli_stmt::fetch returns a boolean. You need to bind your result to variables with mysqli_stmt::bind_result.

Answer (score 0):

With mysqli it is always a pain.

So, if you're going to use raw API calls in your code, [change API](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) then:

```
$sql = "select cap_transaction_id, company_id, company_transaction_id, 
        cap_points, transaction2login 
        from transactions where transaction2login = ?"

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['username']));
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($results);
```

Answer (score -1):

fetch() is not the right function. You should

```
...
$get_orders_stmt->execute();
$res = $get_orders_stmt->get_result();
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
    $results[] = $row;
```

See documentation to choose between fetch_assoc (returning field associative array), fetch_row (returning non-associative array, indexable by column number) and fetch_array(merge between row and assoc)

Comment: hi thanks for the comment - get_result() leads to this error
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() - I have php 5.4.4 installed on apache 2.2. I think this should work but it doesn't!

Comment: sorry, a copy-paste error, I've written $stmt instead of $get_orders_stmt

Comment: oh no - i corrected that part :) the problem seems to be with the get_result() part. i see other folks have had trouble with it and had to change some settings in the ini files. those settings don't seem to exist in my set up

Comment: you know what - thanks for you replies, but I'm going to forget this and try to use pro. everyone says it's better anyhow! thanks. DS

Comment: You're right, get_result() needs mysqlnd. Seems like this driver is default on windows, but not on unix, and has to be configured at compile time.